# Connecting Coax and ADSL networks to the same router

Tags: networking, router, internet, wireless-router

How can I reliably connect the two and is it possible?

I have a modem+router for the coax network and a ADSL backup network setup.
If I connect the modem to the router via Wan Ports, will I be able to also connect my ADSL internet and choose between the two networks when one goes down?

```
Router: P-Link Archer C7, AC1750, Dual Band
Modem: some shady Huawey router that supports wifi and lan connections
```

I have no idea how modems work and it has been provided by the internet company.

Comment: What you need is a dual-wan capable router. This is not complicated. It just requires the right equipment and configuration.

Comment: I have read that you could convert a LAN port to WAN port but this does not seem like a reliable method.
Anyways thank you for the reply :)